# Make_Password returning different hash value for same password

Tags: python, django

i don't want to use django default user table so i created a user table with username and hashed password. I hashed the password with make_password() when posting to database but when i tried retrieving information from the database using the same method to hash user input password, i get a different hash for same password. below is the view code for saving the user and retrieving the details.

view.py

```
class HMUser(APIView):
  def post(self, request):
    request.data['password'] = make_password(request.data['password'])
    print(request.data['password'])
    serialize = serializers.HMUserSerializer(data=request.data)
    if serialize.is_valid():
        serialize.save()
        return Response(1, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    return Response(serialize.errors, 
     status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)


class Login(APIView):
  def get(self, request, username, password):
    print("pass ", password)
    userpassword = make_password(password)
    print("Hash", userpassword)
    user_details = models.HMUser.objects.get(username=username, 
     password=userpassword)
    serialize = serializers.HMUserSerializer(user_details)
    return Response(serialize.data)
```

Comment: Thanks Mahesh, i am taking both username and password but is only the password that's hashed, normal authentication process. I believe i am doing something wrong when hashing.

Comment: What you observe is called salting and an intended security feature.

Comment: Thanks, so what do suggest i do to solve the problem??

Comment: Use `check_password()`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/passwords/#django.contrib.auth.hashers.check_password

Comment: You could print the passwords as bytecode. Maybe -and it's just a guess- some terminating character is appended in one case, e.g. a null-byte, `\n` or something like that

Comment: Mismatching salts is most likely just one of your issues. Why exactly aren't you inheriting from `AbstractBaseUser`?

Comment: Can you please show me how to do that.. i am new to python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mismatch of salt is your problem,

Salt is seed or random number which is used in addition to a password to make it more secure, Since there is no salt specified it generates random at runtime making new value each time for the same password.

Ideal way is to use `check_password()` which is much more friendly,

Workaround is to specify your own salt, something like `make_password(salt='mySalt',password=realPassword)`

You need to ensure that salt use while creating a password and verifying are same.

Comment: **DON'T USE A FIXED SALT!!** That completely defeats the purpose of a salt and allows parallel computation of password hashes for all passwords in your database.